# Restriction of a tensor to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, submanifold

I was wondering that what should a restriction of a tensor field on a submanifold  mean or look like ? To be more precise, suppose I look at $S^{n}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let's denote the normal vector by $N$. Now suppose $M^{n-1}$ is a smooth embedded hypersurface of $S^n$, with normal vector $N'$. If $X$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then it can be written as \begin{equation*} X= Y+fN'+hN \end{equation*} where $Y$ is a vector field on $M$, $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f=\langle X, N'\rangle$ and $h:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $h=\langle X, N\rangle$.

Now suppose I start with a tensor field on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, say a $(1,1)$ tensor field $P$ (or an endomorphism of $T\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ). Can we have an expression for $P$ as above by writing $P$ as some $(1,1)$ tensor field on $M$ plus some other quantities.

Thanks !

Comment: This is a question of linear algebra at each point - in your example, you're just writing the components of $X_p \in T_p \mathbb R^{n+1}$ with respect to the direct sum decomposition $$T_p \mathbb R^{n+1} = T_p M \oplus \langle N' \rangle \oplus \langle N \rangle.$$ Thus the analogue for endomorphisms should just be block matrices: decompose each of $P|_{T_p M}, P(N), P(N')$ into components in the same way.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks for your comment. So can I write $P=P'+fT+hQ$, where $P'$ is an endomorphism of $TM$, $T$ is an endomorphism of $NM$ (the normal space of $M$) and $Q$ is an endomorphism of $NS^{n}$ ?

Comment: No, this is only true if $P$ is "diagonal" with respect to the decomposition. In general there will be nine components - in addition to the three endomorphisms you wrote, you will have linear maps from each of the three factors to each of the other two. You can think of it as a [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) with partition $(n-1,1,1).$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I see. So this means that $P$ will be a sum of $9$ maps of vector spaces, for all $p\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, where, for instance first three will be maps of $TM\rightarrow TM$, $TM\rightarrow NM$ and $TM\rightarrow NS^{n}$, and similarly others. Am I correct ? Also, suppose $P$ is a $constant$ $(1,1)$ tensor. What should happen in that case ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: That's correct. You can view each of these factors as sections of the vector bundles $T^*M \otimes TM, T^* M \otimes NM,$ etc. I'm not sure what you mean by a constant tensor - do you mean having constant components in the standard coordinate system on $T\mathbb R^{n+1}$? There's no immediately obvious consequence - since the tangent spaces of $S^n$ and $M$ change as you move from point to point, the 9 components will not be "constant" in any sense.